# Changing Activity sequence in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on a project, I have three activities. Each time I run the project, After the Splash Screen,Login Screen should show then MainActivity. How do I define the sequence here.

Manifest file:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: The manifest file has nothing to do with that. You should program that logic in your activities.

Comment: As @IvoBeckers answered there's nothing that need to be done in manifest. 
On button click or any other locgic you should start activity according to your need.

Answer (score 2):

The manifest file has nothing to do with the order. You need to put your logic to open activities. For example, in splash screen activity, you can open Login Screen

```
val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

In your login screen when user press on login button you can do

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```